# Speed needed to make a car jump from a ramp

Tags: c#, unity, physics, projectile-physics

I need to make a car jump from a ramp to another, and I need this to be done using AI so I thought it would be enough to set a fixed speed for my car when near the ramp, in order to let it jump correctly.

It works fine if I input the speed manually but I'd like my game to calculate it since the ramps will be generated by user's input.

Unfortunately my physics knowledge lacks, so I need your help.

The problem is summarized in the picture below.

[image: physics problem]

Basically, what I need to compute is the speed (in m/s) that the car has to have on the highest point of the first ramp, given that all the data in red are user's input.

I had some rough ideas on using the projectile range with `x=L, y=h-launchRampHeight` but the results weren't as I expected them so I gave up.

Do you have any hints on this?

Please note that both ramps have the same length (50m).

EDIT:

Based on @mklingen here's the `C#` code that I'm using (where `Distance = L`)

```
var speed = (Mathf.Sqrt(g)*Mathf.Sqrt(Distance)*Mathf.Sqrt((1/Mathf.Sin(Theta)))* Mathf.Sqrt((1/Mathf.Cos(Theta))))/Mathf.Sqrt(2);
```

What happens is quite weird though.

For example, with `theta = 19, L = 196, h = 46` my code returns `80.54646` which seems to work if I input it to the car. However [running the expression in WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ei77488si3o) leads to `55.8` which is wrong.

It may seem that the code is correct but with `theta = 35, L = 261, h = 39` my code returns `NaN` while [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ejvl1bngd44) shows `52.17` which made the jump happen.

So, tu summarize, I have 2 different cases in which my result is different from WolframAlpha's one and none of them is the correct one both the times.

What's going on?

Comment: It sounds like your system and wolfram are using different angle units.

Comment: You're correct, the expression was written in radians while my data was in degrees. I changed the expression to match degrees (just multiplied angles by `57.29578` in Wolfram) and now they both return the same values for the first case. The problem still remains for the second one: now Wolfram returns `-57.4` (which is clearly wrong) while my code still returns `NaN`. So, what happens is that if I change the expression into degrees than the first case is solved, if I change my code into radians than I can solve the second one but I can't solve them together.

Comment: You may want to try math exchange or physics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using kinematics but got a much more complex equation than what you have already..
I think it should work, and I've double-checked the math (and did a bunch of it using wolfram), but I'm wary of it just because of how long the equation came out to be.

where y = the height of the second ramp - the end height of the first ramp, and g is positive

[See solution at wolframalpha.com](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%200%3Dv%5E4%28cos%28t%29%5E2*sin%28t%29%5E2%29%20-%20v%5E2%282*L*cos%28t%29*sin%28t%29%2Bsin%28t%29%5E2%29%20%2B%202*g*y*L%5E2%2C%20v)